# PySpark monotonically_increasing_id results differ locally and on AWS EMR

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr, distributed-computing

I created a small function that would assign a composite id to each row to essentially group rows into smaller subsets, given a subset size. Locally on my computer the logic works flawlessly. Once I deploy and test the Spark application using PySpark on AWS EMR, the results are completely different.

Subset logic:

```
partition_column = "partition"
partitioned_df = dataframe.withColumn(
    partition_column, floor(monotonically_increasing_id() / subset_length)
)
partitioned_df_ids = (
    partitioned_df.select(partition_column)
    .distinct()
    .rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x)
    .collect()
)
for partition_id in partitioned_df_ids:
    temp_df = partitioned_df.filter(col(partition_column) == partition_id)
    dataframe_refs.append(temp_df)
```

Given this function and a dataframe with 77,700 rows, if I set the subset length to 50,000 for example, I would get 2 smaller dataframes. One with 50,000 rows and the other with 27,700 rows.
However, when I test this against AWS EMR PySpark, I'm seeing much smaller subsets ~26 of them not above 3200 per subset.

Possible solution (for review):

```
dataframe_refs = []
partition_window = Window.orderBy(lit(1))
ranges_to_subset_by = []
num_of_rows = dataframe.count()
num_of_splits = math.ceil(num_of_rows / subset_length)

remainder = num_of_rows
start = 0
for _ in range(num_of_splits):
    print(_)
    end = start + subset_length if _ != num_of_splits else start + remainder
    ranges_to_subset_by.append(
        (start + 1, end)
    )
    remainder -= subset_length
    start = end

print(ranges_to_subset_by)

df = dataframe.withColumn("row_number", row_number().over(partition_window))
df.show()

for start, stop in ranges_to_subset_by:
    dataframe_refs.append(df.filter(col("row_number").between(start, stop)))
```

Comment: Per ZygD's answer - what is it you want to achieve by breaking up the datasets in this way?

Comment: @Chris I need to make API calls, where the calls have a max limit of records per call. What I’m thinking to do is iterate through the chucked datasets that has a much smaller number of records

Comment: you could just use ZygD's solution of partition_id and df.groupBy("partition_id").agg(collect_list(struct('all','the','fields')).as('therows')).map( your call go's here and you chunk by max number of rows i) but the data in each partition must be less than 2gb as that's the row size limit.  This would allow your map function to be parallel though

Comment: @Chris could I also do something like what I posted in my original question under Possible solution? Basically, I calculate the number of splits that need to occur, determine how many records are in each split, assign a row number to each row, and capture the row range (start position, end position) to filter by and create a "chunked" dataframe of.

Answer (score 3):

**Explanation why `monotonically_increasing_id` doesn't work for you**

When executing locally, you may only have *one partition* where your data resides. [`monotonically_increasing_id`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id.html#pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id) returns nice sequence of ids for every partition. So, since you have just one partition (locally), you will get nice sequence for which your logic will work.

However, when you have multiple partitions, sequences will have "gaps" between them. Consider this example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.range(10) \
          .withColumn('mono_id', F.monotonically_increasing_id()) \
          .withColumn('partition_id', F.spark_partition_id()) \

df.show()
# +---+----------+------------+
# | id|   mono_id|partition_id|
# +---+----------+------------+
# |  0|         0|           0|
# |  1|         1|           0|
# |  2|         2|           0|
# |  3|         3|           0|
# |  4|         4|           0|
# |  5|8589934592|           1|
# |  6|8589934593|           1|
# |  7|8589934594|           1|
# |  8|8589934595|           1|
# |  9|8589934596|           1|
# +---+----------+------------+
```

`spark_partition_id` results show that `df` is distributed between 2 partitions. And you can see that `monotonically_increasing_id` returns consecutive numbering INSIDE partition, but there is a huge gap between both partitions. So, because of this "gap", your logic does not work.

This is an example with three partitions:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.range(10) \
          .repartition(3) \
          .withColumn('mono_id', F.monotonically_increasing_id()) \
          .withColumn('partition_id', F.spark_partition_id())

df.show()
# +---+-----------+------------+
# | id|    mono_id|partition_id|
# +---+-----------+------------+
# |  3|          0|           0|
# |  4|          1|           0|
# |  6|          2|           0|
# |  0| 8589934592|           1|
# |  1| 8589934593|           1|
# |  7| 8589934594|           1|
# |  8| 8589934595|           1|
# |  2|17179869184|           2|
# |  5|17179869185|           2|
# |  9|17179869186|           2|
# +---+-----------+------------+
```

**How to effectively split your dataset**

Since you have said that grouping logic is not important, as long as the resulting dataset can be effectively split into predefined maximum number of rows, this is an effective method to create a column for partitioning:

```py
subset_len = 3
df = df.rdd.zipWithIndex().toDF().selectExpr("_1.*", f"int(_2 / '{subset_len}') batch")
```

Currently, DataFrame API does not have such method, so we must use RDD's [`zipWithIndex`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.zipWithIndex.html). It doesn't perform shuffling, so it's efficient.

Example:

```py
df = spark.range(10)

subset_len = 3
df = df.rdd.zipWithIndex().toDF().selectExpr("_1.*", f"int(_2 / '{subset_len}') batch")

df.show()
# +---+-----+
# | id|batch|
# +---+-----+
# |  0|    0|
# |  1|    0|
# |  2|    0|
# |  3|    1|
# |  4|    1|
# |  5|    1|
# |  6|    2|
# |  7|    2|
# |  8|    2|
# |  9|    3|
# +---+-----+
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed explanation. It makes sense now why the data is splitting like that. I need to make API calls from a larger dataset, but the api only supports a certain number of records per call. Would bucketing make sense in this case, or does it make sense to chunk the dataframes, and return a list of smaller dataframes to iterate on

Comment: could I also do something like what I posted in my original question under Possible solution? Basically, I calculate the number of splits that need to occur, determine how many records are in each split, assign a row number to each row, and capture the row range length to filter by and create a "chunked" dataframe of.

Comment: The posted "Possible solution" moves everything into one node, as your `partition_window` is defined for the whole dataframe. It would probably work, but it would require more analysis to determine if there are more efficient solutions (which would require more learning and time).

Comment: @dataviews - I have updated the answer with `zipWithIndex` efficient option which I've learned just recently.

Comment: I found `toLocalIterator` to be very applicable to my use case. We are using AWS EMR to run a small cluster that does some transformation operations and needs to make API calls on the final dataset, in small batches. Since the data is scattered around the cluster, we can bring data back to the driver node with this iterator function, hitting each RDD, and make the API call once the queue on the driver reaches the max limit. Found this to be very efficient for my use case. The order of the data does not matter in my use case either.